# selecting record from oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle

To select last record, I was using this when my database was MySQL:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Id 
                         FROM test 
                     ORDER BY LENGTH(Id), Id ASC");

$count = mysql_numrows($result);

if($count != 0) {    
  $lastid = mysql_result($result,$count-1,"Id");    
}
```

...and it works fine.
But now my table is in an Oracle database - I wrote:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT Id 
                            FROM test 
                        ORDER BY LENGTH(Id), Id ASC");

oci_execute($stid);

$p = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT COUNT(ID) 
                         FROM test");

oci_execute($p);

$count = oci_fetch_array($p);

if($count[0] != 0) {    
  $lastid = oci_result($stid, $count[0]-1);
}
```

It doesn't work - I am not getting the last record.

Comment: How do you define the last record? Is it the last one inserted? Why do you need to get it?

Comment: when nothing is in the table i want to insert D1111 and then if i get D1111 i will insert D1112 and then ....9,10,11.Using the code for mysql(upper portion) its just fine.but problem is when database is transfered to oracle(2nd portion of my code).and hypen actually i used to show you the prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [oci_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-result.php), you'll find you're using the second parameter incorrectly.

The second parameter is what you use to retrieve the column - it can be the column name, or the ordinal value.  Ordinal value is a number, starting at one (1) based on the columns specified in the SELECT clause.  Ordinals aren't a recommended practice, because if the query changes -- if you forget to update the ordinal reference your retrieval of values is screwed.  Effectively, the subsequent COUNT query returns a value higher than the number of columns in the first queries SELECT clause.

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT Id 
                            FROM test 
                        ORDER BY LENGTH(Id), Id ASC");

oci_execute($stid);

$lastid = oci_result($stid, 1);
```

`oci_result` lacks the third parameter that `mysql_result` provides.

To make things work in Oracle, use:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT x.id
                            FROM (SELECT Id 
                                    FROM test 
                                ORDER BY LENGTH(Id) DESC, Id DESC) x
                           WHERE ROWNUM = 1");

oci_execute($stid);

$lastid = oci_result($stid, 1);
```

The updated query will return one row, the latest based on reversing the `ORDER BY` you were using previously.

Comment: @Rasel: Run the SQL query directly against Oracle in whatever client you have - SQLPlus, Toad, PLSQLDeveloper.  The second example will only return one value...

Comment: Oh,your query just reverse my query.So what i need is now in the first row.I am going to accept your answer.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

And what are you using this for? If it is to determine the next Id, then **don't do this**, but use a [sequence](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Sequence) instead. If not then you can use `select max(id) from testid` to get the maximum value of the column.

**edit**

First create a sequence to store the sequential number :

```
create sequence testid_seq;
```

Then when you insert a record, use

```
insert into testid(id, ...) values ("D111-" || testid_seq.nextval, ... );
```

And just fill in the dots with the info you want to insert.

Comment: column is not of number type.Its first character is D.And i need sequence D111-1 D111-2 D111-3.max(id) will not work

Comment: You should mention this in your question.

Comment: But are you using it to determine the next id when you insert new records? If so, you still can use a sequence, that just stores the last number of your ID, and then insert that value prefixed with **D111-** in your ID column.

Comment: D111-9 and then D111-10.If it is true for sequence then i can use it.But for me i don't know how to code it in php.And yeah,i am using it to determine the next id when inserting a new record

Comment: I just edited my answer to detail it a bit more, that approach should probably work (it's been a while since I last used Oracle though :p).

Comment: While I agree there are better ways of setting this up, changes like these are not trivial.  It's easy for us to say "change your data model", but we don't have to do the work - very unreasonable when considering people asking these questions could be dealing with 100+K records.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I guess you didn't look at my edit, it details a solution he could use if the numbering behind the prefix is sequential (which, based on his comments, seems to be the case) without any change to his datamodel (apart from setting up a sequence). At first he didn't even say anything specific about the ID itself, so how on Earth should I have known what his id looked like?