# Migrate PHP/Mysql to PHP/Oracle

Tags: php

How can I convert my PHP/Mysql code to PHP/Oracle.
this is my code.

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM employee WHERE name = '".$userName."' and email = '".$userMobile."' and salary = '".$userSalary."' and deductions = '".$userDeductions."'";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
$recResult = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$existName = $recResult["name"];
if($existName=="") {
$insertTable= mysql_query("insert into employee (name, email, salary, deductions) values('".$userName."', '".$userMobile."', '".$userSalary."', '".$userDeductions."');");
```

Comment: What needs to be converted? Looks like standard SQL to me. However, if `salary` and `deductions` are numeric types, you need to remove the quotes around the values.

Comment: even if it were numeric oracle doesnt mind enclosing quotes. however it will be a different case if the value in $userDeductions has any formatting marks

Answer (score 2):

PDO could be one solution. But if you want to continue with the existing, then whats the problem you are getting ?, seems like simple syntax to me. but since PDO is a very good/DB independent way of doing this and hence iam suggesting, You can find an example at http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php.
Btw, this is a rough thing i could make ( didn't get to test it ), please check it. and more information can be found at [selecting record from oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919823/selecting-record-from-oracle)

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM employee WHERE name = '".$userName."' and email = '".$userMobile."' and salary = '".$userSalary."' and deductions = '".$userDeductions."'";
$sql = oci_parse($conn,$query);
oci_execute($sql);
$existName = oci_result($sql, 1);
if($existName=="") {
#...
}
```